# Read/Write circuit to file in Stim

Tags: stim

I'm trying to save and load large circuits from files in Stim. For example, if I use a generated surface code from the intro notebook

```
import stim

circuit = stim.Circuit.generated(
    "surface_code:unrotated_memory_z",
    rounds=100,
    distance=3,
    after_clifford_depolarization=0.001,
    after_reset_flip_probability=0.001,
    before_measure_flip_probability=0.001,
    before_round_data_depolarization=0.001
)
```

The way I would currently save this is with

```
with open('saved_circuit.stim', 'w') as f:
    f.write(circuit.__str__())
```

And then read it with

```
circuit_file = open('saved_circuit.stim', 'r')
circuit_text = circuit_file.read()
circuit_file.close()

circuit = stim.Circuit()
circuit.append_from_stim_program_text(circuit_text)
```

This works fine and all, but I got the feeling that because they went through the trouble of defining the [stim circuit file format (.stim)](https://github.com/quantumlib/Stim/blob/main/doc/file_format_stim_circuit.md#the-stim-circuit-file-format-stim), it seemed that there would be simple methods like `circuit.save('filename.stim')` or `circuit.load('filename.stim')`. But I'm not having any luck finding any methods of the like. Right now my only solution is to define functions that do this, which is not a challenge, but just wondering if it's already an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In stim v1.9+ there's [`stim.Circuit.to_file`](https://github.com/quantumlib/Stim/blob/main/doc/python_api_reference_vDev.md#stim.Circuit.to_file), [`stim.Circuit.from_file`](https://github.com/quantumlib/Stim/blob/main/doc/python_api_reference_vDev.md#stim.Circuit.from_file), [`stim.DetectorErrorModel.to_file`](https://github.com/quantumlib/Stim/blob/main/doc/python_api_reference_vDev.md#stim.DetectorErrorModel.to_file), [`stim.DetectorErrorModel.from_file`](https://github.com/quantumlib/Stim/blob/main/doc/python_api_reference_vDev.md#stim.DetectorErrorModel.from_file).

---

As of stim v1.8 there aren't methods that take a path to read/write a circuit from.

The `__str__` method is guaranteed to produce the file format specified in that document, and the constructor is guaranteed to parse its argument as that format.

Comment: I suppose at some moment of finding time, I could do a merge request with these methods, since it seems trivial to implement as a simple wrapper. Might turn out to be a more delicate issue! Thanks for the response